# Solaris script to scp files from the Solaris server to Linux server

Tags: ssh, solaris

I need to scp some .xml files (of duration April-May 2016) from a Solaris server (Server A) to a Linux server (Server B) where the Solaris server is the home directory where the script is written and will be executed.

I have written the below script for this-

```
#!/bin/sh

ssh server@10.20.14.49 touch --date "2016-04-01" /tmp/start.tmp
ssh server@10.20.14.49 touch --date "2016-05-31" /tmp/end.tmp

for i in `find /home/hs/demo*.xml -type f -newer /tmp/start.tmp -not -newer /tmp/end.tmp`
do
scp server@10.20.14.49:$i dev@10.24.21.11:/data/Output
done
```

But after executing the script from server A it is prompting me for password (which I don't want to happen, as I need the Solaris to automatically scp files without human intervention)

And for doing scp I have created keys using command "ssh-keygen -t rsa" in Solaris server (Server A- 10.20.14.49) and have copied the public key to the Linux server (Server B- 10.24.21.11).

But still after executing the script from server A it is prompting me for password, and so I have created a **config file in Server A under /home/hs/.ssh**, and below are its contents:-

```
Host oa
User dev
HostName 10.24.21.11
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my_ssh_key
```

But still Solaris (Server A) is prompting me for password.

Comment: On target server add your public ssh key in ~/.ssh/autorized_keys

Comment: There may be a problem with permissions on the .ssh directory, or its files - Solaris can be more strict that Linux by default on this. 

Could you check/provide verbose scp output to see if key is being considered / rejected?

Comment: Is your user account on 10.20.14.49 really called `server`?  And your user account on 10.24.21.11 called `dev`?

Answer (score 1):

you may want to use this command instead, if it is available:

ssh-copy-id user@server.com

This will transfer your public key to the remote server and handle the authorized key process for you.

Comment: This command worked perfectly for me, but the key that was inserted on the target server looks nothing like either the public or private key generated by ssh-keygen. So what is this key that is copied? (Admittedly I was working from Linux to Solaris 8, but I expect the rules should be the same.)